# Passing query string parameters in Lambda functions (Netlify)

Tags: javascript, lambda, query-string, netlify

I am trying to pass a query string into my serverless function but it keeps returning an empty object.

```js
    search = (searchTerm) => {
      // let url = `${URL}${searchTerm}`;
      return fetch(`/.netlify/functions/token-hider?search=${searchTerm}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((result) => {
          console.log(result.results);
          return results;
        });
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let searchTerm = input.value;
  search(searchTerm);
});
```

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const qs = require("qs");

exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
  // apply our function to the queryStringParameters and assign it to a variable
  const API_PARAMS = qs.stringify(event.queryStringParameters.search);
  console.log(event);
  // const API_PARAMS = qs.stringify(event.queryStringParameters);
  console.log("API_PARAMS", API_PARAMS);
  // Get env var values defined in our Netlify site UI

  // TODO: customize your URL and API keys set in the Netlify Dashboard
  // this is secret too, your frontend won't see this
  const { KEY } = process.env;
  const URL = `https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?page=1&per_page=50&client_id=${KEY}&query=${API_PARAMS}`;

  console.log("Constructed URL is ...", URL);

  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(URL);
    // refer to axios docs for other methods if you need them
    // for example if you want to POST data:
    //    axios.post('/user', { firstName: 'Fred' })
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    };
  } catch (error) {
    const { status, statusText, headers, data } = error.response;
    return {
      statusCode: error.response.status,
      body: JSON.stringify({ status, statusText, headers, data }),
    };
  }
};
```

it works when i hard code the query string, and i can console log the search term and it is defined.

Comment: _"it works when i hard code the query string"_  hard-code it _where_? What does `console.log("API_PARAMS", API_PARAMS)` show?

Answer (score 0):

Since Netlify redirect mechanism is not able to provide you the data of which rule it matched, you could try to match the original request in your function to determine what it should do.

Hope this helps you solve your specific issue!

[Here is the reference](https://answers.netlify.com/t/querystringparameters-not-working-with-redirect-on-production/3828/30)

Comment: Hi There. Link based answers could be comments.